# How does Array#select method exactly works in ruby? And why it returns an empty array or the original one?

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, arraycollection

I have this code

```
arr = [1, 2, 3].select do |n|
  n + 2
  puts n
end
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
```

and the return value is

```
[]
```

Then I have this code

```
arr = [1, 2, 3].select do |n|  
  n + 2
end
```

and the return value is

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

So I know that Array#select invokes the block passing in successive elements from self, returning an array containing those elements for which the block returns a true value. How does it behave in those code examples so I could understand why it returns these values.

Answer (score 5):

[`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) creates a new array using the elements of your array that return truthy from the block.

In your first case, the last line of your block is a `puts` statement which always returns nil. Hence the `[]`.

In your second case, the last line of your block is always a number, so always truthy. Hence the output equals the input.

Comment: And why in the first code example it doesn't return [nil, nil, nil]?

Comment: It makes a subset of your Array using only the elements that return truthy. The elements that return nil, don't get added at all.

Comment: Actually I know why ...because everything in ruby is truthy except false and nil?

Comment: Yes. select is only going to give you the same element you started with or nothing. If you want to change the elements, you might be more interested in Array#map. For example, [1,2,3].map{ |n| n+2} would be [3,4,5].

Comment: I know about map. I am learning Ruby at online bootcamp and in the tests they require us to understand how select, map and each really work behind the scenes. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`Array#select` returns a new array with all the elements that returned `true` from the block. It does this by iterating over each element, passing it to the block, running the block if the block returns true it puts the element in the new array if not it will skip it and once done it will return a new array.

With that said there are a few other things we should know first before delving into the problem you're having.

1) In Ruby there's a concept called Truthiness. That means that every element except for `nil` and `false` evaluates to `true`. Take for example if I ran this conditional

```
if 'happy puppy'
  puts "I'm the happiest puppy"
end
```

You'd see that `I'm the happiest puppy` is output. That's because the string, not being `false` or `nil`, will evaluate to `true`. Conversely if ran this code

```
if nil
  puts "Truthiness means all things evaluate to true except nil and false"
end
```

In this example, the conditional wouldn't output the string because `nil` doesn't evaluate to true.

2) Pay careful attention to what a method outputs and returns. In the case of Kernel#Puts it outputs `n` and returns `nil`. When the block being passed to `Array#select` is invoked it runs each line of code in the block including `puts`. That's why we see each number output. Then, this is the important part, it returns `nil`. Now remember the rules of Truthiness? Because this is the last line of code in the block it's the implicit return of the entire block. That means the block will return `nil` which evaluates to false.

3) Now on to `Array#select`, it works by iterating over each element in an array and invoking the block on it. Based on the return value of the block it'll decide whether or not the element belongs in the return array. In your first example, `puts` is used on the last line and returns `nil` which means that the block will always evaluate to false. That's why it outputs the element but then returns an empty array. In the second example, the last line in the block is `n+2` which will evaluate to an integer. This is where truthiness comes in to play, an integer (or anything besides false or nil) will always evaluate to true. This means the block always returns true. That's why all the elements are returned in the array.